# Accumulating SOAP responses together with SOAP requests through wso2esb mediation

Tags: soap, wso2, aggregation, wso2-esb

I have a SOAP web service which can be accessed like:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:sys="system">
  <soap:Body>
    <sys:getAccountInfo>
        <account id="132456"/>
    </sys:getAccountInfo>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This web service would provide the following response:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <S:Body>
    <ns1:getAccountInfoResponse xmlns:ns1="system">
      <balance value="555">
    </ns1:getAccountInfoResponse>
  </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

My challenge is to provide a proxyfying service which can accept multiple accounts as an input and respond with balance for each one like the following:
Request into proxy:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:sys="systemProxy" xmlns:inner="innerProxyNamespace">
  <soap:Body>
    <sys:getAccountInfo>
      <inner:account id="123456"/>
      <inner:account id="123457"/>
      <inner:account id="123458"/>
    </sys:getAccountInfo>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Proxy response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:sys="systemProxy" xmlns:inner="innerProxyNamespace">
  <soap:Body>
    <sys:getAccountInfoResponse>

      <inner:account id="123456">
        <inner:balance value="555"/>
      </inner:account>

      <inner:account id="123457">
        <inner:balance value="666"/>
      </inner:account>

      <inner:account id="123458">
        <inner:balance value="777"/>
      </inner:account>

    </sys:getAccountInfoResponse>
  </soap:Body>
<soap:Envelope>
```

I am using **Iterate** and **Aggregate** mediator for splitting incoming request into multiple requests to backend and accumulating responses from backend into single message. The problem is I can not find the right way to include `account id` into proxy response even with **Enrich** mediator.

I do iteration sequence like this:

```
<!-- it is correct proxy incoming message format -->
<iterate attachPath="soap:Body/sys:getAccountInfo"
    expression="$body/sys:getAccountInfo/account"
    preservePayload="true"
    xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:sys="systemProxy">
  <target>
    <sequence>
      <payloadFactory>
        <!-- payloadFactory configuration skipped -->
      </payloadFactory>
      <enrich>
        <source clone="true" type="body"/>
        <target property="originalRequest" type="property"/>
      </enrich>
      <send>
        <endpoint key="BackendEndpoint"/>
      </send>
    </sequence>
  </target>
</iterate>
```

So the question is - what is the right way to aggregate all response messages from backend into one preserving data from the original request?

Answer (score 0):

I used **Propetry** and **PayloadFactory** mediators *before* the **Aggregate** mediator. It let me include request into response before aggregation. Then I aggregated them all together.